# HashMap with BitmapDrawable not returning drawable

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, android-drawable

i have a HashMap like this

```
HashMap<String, BitmapDrawable> bitmapDrawables = new HashMap<String, BitmapDrawable>();
```

Now i have a method which will return the drawable:

```
public static BitmapDrawable getDrawable(String fileName, Context context,Bitmap bitmap) {
    BitmapDrawable drawable = bitmapDrawables.get(fileName);
    if (drawable == null) {
        drawable = convertBitmapToDrawable(bitmap, context);// will convert the bitmap to drawable
        bitmapDrawables.put(fileName, drawable);

    }
    return drawable;
    }
```

It works fine but some times it will not return the proper drawable, like i have 2 Activities A and B,in Activity A i have a button with drawable set, now i move from A -> B and then come back to A at that time the drawable is not loading, but when i touch that button the drawable is visible.

Why this is happening?, i have removed the haspMap and checked it its loads properly and when i move from A->B and come back to A,but if i dont use the Hashmap there is lag in the screens.

i am using the getDrawable() in this fashion:

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(name,context,bitmap);
```

Comment: How and where do you use getDrawable() method?

Comment: In onCreate() as usual

Comment: I suspect the issue is not in this method, but in convertBitmapToDrawable() one.

Comment: @beworker this is how i am converting new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);

Comment: Hmmm. Everything you've shown us is perfectly fine. What if you put button.invalidate() in onResume() method? Does it work then?

Comment: @beworker yes i tried that, but still its same

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(name,context,bitmap)
```

in method `onResume()`. By the way, your implementation is not recommended， will cause memory leak easily. See [this](http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/) for more detail